# Scroll android maps pragmatically

Tags: android, google-maps, accelerometer

I am trying to build an android app to scroll over android maps API v2 in android studio. I want to scroll the maps in all different directions using the phone's Accelerometer sensor. For example if the phone is tilted 45 degree to the right, I want the map to be contentiously moving in 45 degree to the right. From what I already found I can only moveCamera (scroll) by latlong target or by pixels, Is there any way to do so using the angle of X , Y coordination? 
These are samples of what I have tried:
1- Move camera by latlang target.

```
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(MOUNTAIN_VIEW)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
            .zoom(20)                   // Sets the zoom
            .bearing(20)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
            .tilt(10)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 1000, null);
```

2- Find phone angle from X,Y using Accelerometer:

```
        float X = (float)Math.round(event.values[0]);
        float Y= (float)Math.round(event.values[1]);
        float angle = (float) (Math.atan2(X, Y)/(Math.PI/180));
```

I would appreciate any new idea to do this or a way to moveCamera by angle.

Comment: What does "contentiously moving in 45 degree to the right" mean? You mean 45 degrees per second? How do you translate the tilt amplitude of the phone (degrees) to a speed in moving the camera?

Comment: @MehmetKologlu When I change the phone's angle, I can use onSensorChanged method to contentiously scroll the camera on the same direction as the phone. My biggest problem is wheneven I want to use  animateCamera of moveCamera, I still need to put the next  target point, whereas in my case there is no specific target.

Comment: Use animateCamera and animate the camera to a point that is (degrees times a constant) off the center of the current view. Do this animation while a case like 'deviceTilted == true'

Comment: @MehmetKologlu I would appreciate a simple example from you, because honestly I didn't get what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will just move the camera by pixels equal to the magnitude of the device tilt, over one second.

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(x, y), 1000, null);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I tried it manually and worked, Now I have to adjust it with the sensor and wait to get maps loaded before moving.